# Creating a docked music player for SoundCloud and mp3s

Tags: soundcloud, jplayer

I'm trying to create a website that pulls free songs from multiple sources and lets users play them by clicking on their cover art, and launching them in a docked music player on the bottom of the page. Soundcloud's api offers me a lot of songs, but they are in a streaming api format, not in mp3 form.

The music players that SoundCloud offers are great for these streaming songs, but it won't work with the mp3s I'm pulling from other sites. Mp3 players like Jplayer are great for the mp3s, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the streaming soundcloud format.

Think of a site like ex.fm: http://ex.fm/search/bob%20dylan
They pull their audio tracks from many sources but it is all playable through their one player.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check SoundCloud API 
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

There is a `stream_url` property for every track that's streamable outside of SoundCloud.

You need to register your app on Soundcloud and get API Key. With that key you can stream the tracks in your own player.

**Edit**, thanks to [gryzzly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236135/gryzzly). Example of SoundCloud API used with jPlayer:

```
var SOUNDCLOUD_API = 'http://api.soundcloud.com',
    CLIENT_ID = '?client_id=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_CLIENT_ID';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var apiRequest;

  $.get(SOUNDCLOUD_API + '/tracks/6981096.json' + CLIENT_ID)
   .done(handleRepsonse);

  function handleResponse (soundData) {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
      ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          // stream_url is good enough for jPlayer,
          mp3: soundData.stream_url + CLIENT_ID
        });
      },
      swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js"
    });
  }

});
```

And you can check it live at [jsbin.com/ajaken/4/edit](http://jsbin.com/ajaken/4/edit)

Comment: what cucko said is correct – here's a working example of jPlayer using SoundCloud API – http://jsbin.com/ajaken/4/edit Check out the code. @cucko could you pelase insert the relevant JS code in your answer for others to have immediate reference? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you could even insert the link to jsbin in your answer, that'd be quite cool too :-)

Comment: Awesome! I was just missing the ?client_id after the stream_url and it wasn't working. Thank you